# How can you zoom out using JavaScript in MobileSafari?

Tags: javascript, iphone, mobile-safari, zooming

When you double tap or select an input field, it will zoom in. I would assume making an input BLUR would automatically zoom back to previous zoomlevel, however this does not occur and the user has to manually zoom out again. Can this also be done by javascript?

Answer (score 0):

That is the default behavior of iOS safari browser. this happens particularly on selectboxes.

to avoid this please override the font-size provided default by jqm.
you can do something like this.

```
.ui-select .ui-btn select{
font-size: 50px;
}
```